# Using POST requests in Selenium testing

Tags: scala, selenium, cucumber

I'm currently trying to create a test for a POST request using Selenium and Cucumber but I'm not getting anywhere. There doesn't seem to be any kind of solution and I'm at a loss trying to create the test off the top of my head. I'm coding in Scala.
Any ideas?

Comment: Solution for what?

Comment: Are you trying to post a form or post to a rest interface? Ask as if you were writing a defect, so people can understand what you expect, what you tried, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium and Cucumber are each designed for user-actor testing, and your regular user wouldn't be manually submitting POST requests. They would be interacting with the web page using a browser.

A POST is the result of a submitted web form, so make a web form that submits the desired POST, and have Selenium/Cucumber load that page, fill in data, and submit that form to induce the desired POST.

Comment: Cucumber is actually fine here, as there's no reason why a BDD rule can't be implemented by an HTTP/REST test - but you're quite right that interactive tools like Selenium are completely wrong for the job.

Comment: @AndrewRegan It's functionally capable, but I think it's a poor fit. Users aren't sending manual REST requests. Unless OP is testing an application that has been specced in a manner a la "As an API client, I want to make a POST request, so that I can get JSON", which would be kind of weird, it seems like unnecessary overhead.